# About Jimi Hendrix

Tags: rock, guitar

Why is **Jimi Hendrix** called the **Father of Guitar**? What are the unique playing-style of guitar about him. There are many best guitarist like **G-3**, **Jimmy Pages**, **Eric Clapton**, etc. What are the difference between them? Well they have different styles of playing, but why **Jimi Hendrix** called the **Father of Guitar**.

Comment: I don't remember him being called like that, could you share the sources with us?

Comment: actually i was found that on newspaper. Its was on the topic about 27-club if i remembered. I need to  find that note on the web. I'll post it on here as soon as possible, so i need little time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jimi was inspirational for many guitarists because he combined technical proficiency, experimentation, and showmanship.  This mixture would start the whole "guitar hero" phenomenon in the late 1960s, with other guitarists following his lead.  The fact that he died so early allowed other guitarists to fill the void and build a legend around Jimi.

A documentary film here describes this phenomenon: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3690290/

Comment: okay thank you and thanks for the  documentary film